Comedy movie with supposedly invincible man fighting in a church
This one might be a bit vague, but it's been bothering my friends and I. As we recall it's a comedy where one of the final scenes takes place in a church or something similar and the main character, who, for some reason thinks he's invincible, makes a run for the bad guys and gets shot at, doesn't get hit, but later shows multiple holes in his coat. I'm pretty sure that after this scene takes place, he exits the church and there are more bad guys out there.
I'm pretty sure it's an American movie, and it was definitely in English.  If memory serves, it was also a comedy, or at least had several comedic scenes.  If I had to take a guess, I'm also pretty sure it's somewhat recent - say in the 2000's somewhere.  I saw it on TV, though I'm thinking it was probably in the theaters at some point. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please [edit] in any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Yes, please provide more details, as I'm pretty sure I know what you're after but they would really help...

@scorpio47 Are you the same person as "Chad"?

I know the answer but I can't answer, so I'll comment instead. The movie is called Shanghai Noon and it's a western type comedy starring Jackie Chan and Owen Wilson. In the final battle of the movie Owen Wilson character who missed every shot so far attacks a sheriff who empties his pistol but misses all the shots (Owen Wilson later shows his cloak full of holes) and gets hit by a single shot from OW. Later him and Jackie charge outside of the church guns blazing towards bad guys.

@scorpio47 Welcome to Movies & TV. If you're indeed the same user as the asker, you might want to merge your two accounts using the procedure described here in order to use the site's features to its fullest, including being able to edit your question and accept any possibly correct answers.

The movie is called Shanghai Noon and it's a western type comedy starring Jackie Chan and Owen Wilson. 
In the final battle of the movie Owen Wilson character who missed every shot so far attacks a sheriff who empties his pistol but misses all the shots (Owen Wilson later shows his cloak full of holes) and gets hit by a single shot from OW.
Later him and Jackie charge outside of the church guns blazing towards bad guys.
